# How to determine and prove how many solutions does the equation $x^4+x^2=1+\sin(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I suppose that we use intermediate value theorem to start from, but how do you pick the endpoint. If we know there is at least $n$ solutions, how do we use Rolle's Theorem to prove that there are no more than $n$ solutions?

Comment: Hint: it always helps to determine first whether the number of solutions is even or odd.

Comment: You could also think about the interval in which these solutions should lie. The fact that $0<1+\sin(x)<2$ and $x^4+x^2<2$ only for a very small domain may help you in your analysis.

Comment: How can a 4th degree equation have more than $4$ solutions

Comment: @ArchisWelankar it is not a polynomial equation of fourth degree. It involves $\sin x$.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^4+x^2-1-\sin x$. Then $f(0)=-1<0$ and $f(-\pi/2)>0$. Thus at least one root in $(-\pi/2,0)$.

Comment: Also $f(1)=1-\sin 1 >0$. Thus another root in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Thought that a small graph could help in determining the solution.

[image]